# What is the meaning of TL in LiDAR point clouds data sets?

Tags: lidar, usgs

I am exploring some USGS LiDAR data sets and found several occurrences of data sets with the same name except that one had the acronym "TL" in its name and the other not. Example of this is:

- [USGS Lidar Point Cloud NM RioSanJose 2016](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5d00d8b0e4b0573a18f57d32)
- [USGS Lidar Point Cloud NM RioSanJose TL 2016](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5d2c7d26e4b038fabe22c021)

What is the meaning of "TL"? And how will it make the point cloud different from the the other data set?

My online searches gave nothing and the only possibility I can think of would be Topographic Lines but I could not confirm so far.

**Edit:** The links do not point to the same tile, but more examples are found in [this FTP](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/LPC/Projects/)

Comment: I can't answer your question. But your two dataset are not at the same location. So I guess they are expected to have different names.

Comment: Yes I know the pages I linked are not referencing the same tile, I only linked them for proving the naming and showing that the description does not clarify this acronym :) But I have other data sets with the same number of tiles in it and the same names besides this "TL" mention. So I was wondering the difference... They are pretty heavy data sets so I wanted to know which one to download mainly wrt my end goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "TL" stands for Tribal Land.  These areas are coincident with tribal lands and were pulled out of the original project in order to await approval from tribal authorities before publishing the "TL" part of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Adding more details confirming the answer from @keythread, of how one can confirm that TL means Tribal Lands:

USGS data sets with the acronym "_TL_" can be found on [this page](https://usgs.entwine.io/).

One can see that the scanned zones match with the Native American Areas of [this map](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=98263d81550c4ecbbc4e504fbdd4e1c9).